# Matplotlib plot to QtGraphicsView

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, qt-designer

Having trouble finding a way to embed my matplotlib plot to a QGraphicsView object in this GUI that I'm designing. Should I try converting the plot to a PIL image or is there a way to directly embed a matplotlib plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, if you are trying to display an image on qt graphics, try saving it with the below function first.

```
plt.savefig('image1.png', transparent = True, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

then you can just use pixmap and set scene to display on the graphics view.